# Class Shadowing : Is it necessary to keep the same group ID as the original one in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, classpath

I want to patch a class which is present in `main.jar(its a maven project)`. Is it really necessary to create the `patch` project with same `group ID(com.naveen.personal.mainapp)` of the `main.jar`?

My java and maven versions are listed below.
Java Version : 1.7 
Maven version : 3.2.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read this: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Choosing+your+Coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to have the same `group ID(com.naveen.personal.mainapp)` of the `main.jar`. We can have `any group ID` for the `patch project`.